# Warum hat »nächtlich« einen Umlaut und »weihnachtlich« keinen?

Tags: spelling, umlaut

*Weihnachtlich* und *nächtlich* sind Adjektive, die vom gleichen Wort abgeleitet sind. Warum hat ein Wort einen Umlaut und das andere keinen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deine Grundannahme ist falsch *"weihnachtlich"* leitet sich nicht direkt von *"der Nacht"* sondern von *"Weihnacht"* ab. Siehe dazu: [canoo](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation/weihnachtlich:A])

Im Gegensatz dazu leitet sich *"nächtlich"* direkt von *"Nacht"* ab.

Hier kommt es bei der Bildung mit dem Suffix *-lich* zu einer Anpassung des Stammes.

Diese Stammanpassung wird bei *"Weihnacht-lich"* ausgelassen.

[Das Wörterbuch nach Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GW13967) gibt uns folgende Informationen:
(hervorhebung von mir)

> **WEIHNACHTLICH**, adj. und adv. belegt seit Rompler v. Löwenhalt 1 (1647) 199, gebucht seit Campe 5 (1811) 643a, **mit umlaut** in älterer spr.

Es scheint, dass weihnachtlich Ursprünglich **mit** Umlaut  gebildet wurde. Dieser wurde dann im Laufe der Zeit fallengelassen.

Comment: Laut Google wird «weihnächtlich» am ehesten noch unter der Top-Level-Domain CH verwendet. Die Variantengrammatik weist ebenfalls darauf hin, dass «weihnächtlich» eine schweizerische Nebenform ist, vgl. [weihnachtlich / weihnächtlich – Variantengrammatik des Standarddeutschen](http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/Weihnachtlich_/_weihn%C3%A4chtlich).

Comment: *Deine Grundannahme ist falsch "weihnachtlich" leitet sich nicht direkt von "der Nacht" sondern von "Weihnacht" ab* - OP hat doch nicht behauptet, dass es eine **direkte** Ableitung ist. Daher finde ich es etwas hart, die Grundannahme als "falsch" zu bezeichnen: dass *die Nacht* in die Ahnenreihe von "weihnachtlich" gehört, ist ja nicht falsch...

Comment: @Arsak Änderungsvorschläge (bzw. Änderungen) sind wilkommen. Wenn's mir zu arg ist kann ich ja zurückrollen.

Answer (score -1):

Deutsch ist keine grammatisch perfekte Sprache - es gibt immer Ausnahmen, die die Regel bestätigen.

Du hast Recht, theoretisch müsste "weinachtlich" mit Umlaut geschrieben werden. Doch wie Vogel612 denke ich auch, dass der Umlaut im Laufe der Zeit aus Bequemlichkeitsgründen einfach weggefallen ist.